# Failing Cronjob in TYPO3 - Malformed parser URI - direct_mail

Tags: cron, typo3, content-management-system, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

At the moment scheduler tasks of EXT:direct_mail are failing. The cronjob gets the wrong URL.

http:///usr/www/users/myuser/myproject/current/typo3 which breaks setting up a draft mail with direct mail schedular.

```
["code"]=>
  int(1436717322)
  ["message"]=>
  string(96) "The parsedUri "http:///usr/www/users/myuser/myproject/current/typo3" appears to be malformed"
  ["file"]=>
  string(90) "/usr/www/users/myuser/myproject/releases/48/Web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Uri.php"
  ["line"]=>
```

Our cronjob:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php74 -d allow_url_fopen='on' -d allow_url_fopen='on /usr/www/users/myuser/myproject/current/typo3 scheduler:run > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is partly because TYPO3 uses the `HTTP_HOST` variable to create absolute URLs. This is available by default when invoked via CLI. Then it can happen that the path on the server is used instead of the domain. It was finally solved by setting the cronjob like this:

```
* * * * * env HTTP_HOST=www.my-domain.com /usr/bin/php74 -d allow_url_fopen='on' /usr/home/username/public_html/myproject/current/typo3 scheduler:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This ensures that the `HTTP_HOST` variable is available.